# Question about remark in Vistoli's notes on descent

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, descent

Section 4.1.1 of Vistoli's [Notes on Grothendieck topologies, fibered categories and descent theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412512v4.pdf) motivates the formalism of stacks via topological spaces.

Proposition 4.1 says that given an open cover $(U_i\to U)$, every family of bundles $(X_i\to U_i)$ equipped with transition isomorphisms satisfying the cocycle relations gives rise to a bundle $X\to U$ which pulls back to $X_i\to U_i$ along $U_i\to U$.

The remark following proposition 4.1 says that the fact we may glue bundles as well as continuous maps into a fixed codomain means the codomain fibration of topological spaces is a stack.

---

1. I think the words "open cover" are not relevant to proposition 4.1: a family of bundles over the $U_i$ with transition isomorphisms satisfying the cocycle condition always yields a bundle over $U$ for *any* family $U_i\to U$, by the same proof.
2. I don't see how proposition 4.1 implies the codomain fibration of spaces is a stack. I think the key result is that singleton covers associated to open covers are effective descent morphisms, i.e that the *category* of bundles over $U$ is equivalent to the *category* of descent data. The fact bundles merely glue together does not mean *all* bundles over $U$ arise this way.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @1: What about $U_i \to U$ being the inclusion of a closed subspace? Or the family of all points of your space, such that you get no glueing data, why is this giving a bundle?

Comment: @Johann if $U_i\to U$ is the inclusion of a closed subset and $X_i\to U_i$ is a bundle then we have the bundle $X_i\to U_i\to U$. If $(U_i\to U)$ is the family of points and we have a family $X_i\to U_i$ then we have the bundle $\amalg_iX_i\to \amalg _iU_i\to U$. The procedure described in the proof of proposition 4.1 works and seems to be purely categorical.

Comment: Ah I took 'bundle' to be a shorthand for vector bundle, I apologize for not checking the source. In this case I agree that any continuous family would work.

Comment: So you use the word "bundle" to mean *any* continuous map $X\rightarrow U$ ? I agree that gluing topological spaces over $U$ does not mean that (Cont) is a stack over (Top). But there is something more : you can glue continuous maps. For this, you really need open covers. Gluing maps has a consequence for gluing spaces over $U$ : the gluing will be unique (up to unique isomorphism). If you allow any cover, the gluing won't be unique in general.

Comment: In other words, let $\mathcal{F}:(Top)\rightarrow (Cat)$ bet the functor $U\mapsto (Top)/U$. If $\{U_i\rightarrow U\}$ is any cover (not necessarily an open cover), let $\mathcal{F}(\{U_i\rightarrow U\})$ be the category of descent data. Then $\mathcal{F}(U)\rightarrow\mathcal{F}(\{U_i\rightarrow U\})$ is essentially surjective and faithful, but it is not full. So this is not an equivalence of category.

Comment: @Roland locally finite closed covers also admit a pasting lemma. Am I right in assuming they are also of effective descent?

Comment: @Roland also, could you explain why fullness gives essential uniqueness of gluing? It seems to me that conservativity of the latter functor should mean essential uniqueness of gluings. I don't have intuition for fullness of faithfulness (which here should probably be almost equivalent to conservativity).

Comment: @Arrow Think about the case of vector bundles. Let $E$ and $F$ be two vector bundles of rank $n$ on $U$. Imagine you want to cover $U$ with its set of points $\{x\}_{x\in X}$. You can certainly find an isomorphism between the image of $E$ and $F$ in $\mathcal{F}(\{x\rightarrow U\})$ since you only need to specify an isomorphism fiberwise. But there is no gluing of maps, so the data of fiberwise isomorphisms won't be enough to produce an isomorphism between $E$ and $F$. As a matter of fact, vector bundles on each points can be glued in a lot of different ways.

Comment: The main problem is that between different gluing, there might not be enough maps. Let $\phi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}(\{U_i\rightarrow U\})$. In many cases $\phi$ will be faithful (this is because equality of morphisms can be checked locally) **and** conservative (this is because you can also check locally if a morphism is an iso). But this won't give uniqueness of gluing since you need at least a map between two gluing. (I said that iso can be checked locally, but for $Top/U$ this is not true for closed covering...)

Comment: For locally finite closed covering, I am not entirely sure. Can you adapt the proof of Vistoli ? As you said, there is a pasting lemma, so this might indeed work.

Comment: @Roland in your first comment I am struggling with "gluing maps has a consequence for gluing spaces over $U$": given an arrow of canonical descent data $({\begin{smallmatrix}X\\
\downarrow\\
U
\end{smallmatrix}|_{U_{i}}}\overset{f_{i}}{\longrightarrow}{\begin{smallmatrix}Y\\
\downarrow\\
U
\end{smallmatrix}|_{U_{i}}})$ how does a pasting lemma along $(U_i\to U)$ say anything about possible gluings of these bundle arrows to an arrow $\begin{smallmatrix}X\\
\downarrow\\
U \end{smallmatrix} \to\begin{smallmatrix}Y\\
\downarrow\\
U \end{smallmatrix}$?

Comment: @Arrow Did you remove a comment saying all was clear ? ;) Well, a pasting lemma says that the map $X\rightarrow Y$ over $U$ exists. This is an important feature of stacks ! If the $f_i$ define an isomorphism of descent data, and if the maps does not glue, then there is no uniqueness of gluing objects : $X$ and $Y$ are locally isomorphic *with descent data* but not isomorphic. Again : look at examples, descent of fiber bundles along the covering of $U$ by its points.

Comment: @Roland I did :D. I'll try to clarify my confusion. By "pasting lemma" I mean a statement of the form "a coherent family of continuous maps $U_i\to X$ may be glued (uniquely) along $(U_i\to U)$ to a continuous map $U\to X$. I understood from your comment that this has consequences for gluing bundles, and I am asking why. If by gluing morphisms you instead means "gluing morphisms of bundles", which seems to be the case, then I think I understand you. Also, the example of the point-cover is very instructive, thanks. I am not sure why the functor is essentially surjective in that case though.

Comment: Yes a pasting lemma is what you wrote, but it implies a pasting lemma for bundles : if $f_i:X_i\rightarrow Y_i$  are maps over $U_i$ which are "coherent" then they can be glued along $X_i\rightarrow X$ to a continuous map $f:X\rightarrow Y$. And of course, this continuous map is a map in $Top/U$. (Here I am assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are already given since we are talking about uniqueness of gluing).

Comment: @Roland ah, that is clear, but that is a property of the $X_i\to X$, not $U_i\to U$. Okay :)

Comment: Sure, in general stacks, we need gluing of morphisms (in $F(U_i)$).

Comment: @Roland yep. Okay! Infinite thanks! I guess I'll delete this question or write a short answer, unless you want to.

Comment: No don't delete the question. Either write a short answer, or leave it like this.

Comment: @Roland just to make sure: in the category of topological spaces, descent data is always effective right? Is there a simple example of non-effective descent data?

Comment: With usual open covering ? (I have to ask, because from your questions I am not sure). In that case, yes, this is always effective. You can construct artificial noneffective descent data (take any stack $F$ but change $F(X)$ to be the empty category), a more interesting one : if $F$ is a presheaf (that is take values in discrete categories), then a descent data is the same thing as sections on $U_i$ which coincide on overlaps, but if $F$ is not a sheaf, descent data may not be effective.

Comment: @Roland haha are my questions that bad? I meant for any surjective family (cover), open or not. I now see your [second comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425026/question-about-remark-in-vistolis-notes-on-descent#comment5010071_2425026) says the answer is yes. In fact I don't even think the family should be surjective - the gluing of the descent data might yield a bundle with empty fibers

Comment: No they are not bad, it is just that they are unusual... And you are right, if you take a family which is not surjective, the functor $F(U)\rightarrow F(\{U_i\rightarrow U\}) is still essentially surjective. This time it is not even full, this is because you have no control whatsoever on the fiber not covered by the family. They might be empty, but might also be anything...

Comment: @Roland so essential surjectivity is really due to the well-pointedness of the category of topological spaces, and fullness fails for the family of points because a family of fibers may vary in many ways (e.g non-isomorphic locally trivial bundles with a fixed fiber), and a descent datum along the family of points does not dictate "how" the fibers should vary over the base. Is this a reasonable summary?

Comment: What do you mean by well-pointedness ? Topological spaces are flexible enough so that essential surjectivity hold in many cases indeed. Fullness fails for closed covering in general (except maybe locally finite one as you remarked before).

Comment: @Roland well-pointedness means continuous functions are determined by their values on points (the terminal object is a [separator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator)). Regarding fullness, I will try to think about it. Interestingly, [Reiterman and Tholen](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864194900337) have characterized effective descent morphisms of topological spaces, and since fully-faithfulness of the induced functor is equivalent a sheaf condition on the "bundle hom", perhaps topological descent is "determined" by sheaf theory (not restricting to open covers).

Comment: Ok so I don't think that essential surjectivity is due to well-pointedness. In fact I don't see any relationship right now, maybe you can expand a little bit. I am also not sure I fully understand what you mean by "determined by sheaf theory". Of course, being a stack requires that Homs are sheaves for fully-faithfulness of the descent data functor.

Comment: @Roland ahh, sorry. I meant to say *faithfulness* for any surjective family is due to well pointedness. Essential surjectivity probably depends on many geometric properties of the category of topological spaces which make the colimit construction of gluing along descent data possible. As for the "determined by sheaf theory", you remarked earlier that the gluing of bundle arrows is furnished by the gluing lemma for arrows of spaces - sheaf theory. So perhaps the effective descent morphisms of spaces are exactly the ones which give 0-dimensional descent i.e sheaf property..

Comment: I am not sure for well pointedness. For example, the category of sheaves is a stack but is not well pointed (if I have well understood the definition). As for your second statement, well, in fact I am not sure I can formulate a precise sentence about it. Can you ? What do you mean by "morphisms which give sheaf property" ?

Comment: @Roland by "surjective family" I meant the concrete case of a surjective family of continuous mappings. I am not saying well-pointedness is necessary for faithfulness, just that it's the property of topological spaces ensuring it. I will try to think of a precise sentence in the upcoming days. Tentatively by a "morphism which gives a sheaf property" I meant a one-arrow analogue of a family $(U_i\to U)$ which gives the sheaf property, i.e such that a family $(U_i\to X)$ lifts uniquely to a continuous map $U\to X$ restricting to the $U_i \to X$.

Comment: @Roland I think locally closed covers will not be effective descent families. If I didn't make (too many) mistakes, proofs require existence and uniqueness of gluing sinks in $\mathsf C$ along *pullbacks* of $(U_i\to U)$. However, it seems not much can be said about the pullback of a locally finite closed family...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed Proposition 4.1 holds for an arbitrary family of bundles. The proof is the same.

Indeed Proposition 4.1 does not imply the codomain fibration of topological spaces is a stack. The stack property depends on properties of open covers. Without them, the induced functor to the category of descent data will not be an equivalence.

As suggested in the comments, the example of covering a space $U$ by its family of points is instructive in demonstrating how the canonical functor may be faithful and even essentially surjective without being full (without the possibility of gluing bundle arrows).